# Exception when Scaffold-DbContext with IBM.EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, db2, entity-framework-core

When using the command in the package manager console window in VS2017 Professional

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=server;uid=username;pwd=password;database=database" IBM.EntityFrameworkCore -force
```

With these dependencies:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.3.0.100" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.4" />
      <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm encountering the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.IScaffoldingProviderCodeGenerator, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IAnnotationCodeGenerator, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ICSharpUtilities)'.
   at IBM.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.Db2CSharpDbContextGenerator..ctor(IScaffoldingProviderCodeGenerator providerCodeGenerator, IAnnotationCodeGenerator annotationCodeGenerator, ICSharpUtilities cSharpUtilities)
```

It should be noted that there is another project in the same solution also using EntityFramework Core for SQL Server that is generating the DB Context fine with the Scaffold-DbContext command.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did you by chance figured out a solution?

Comment: No we didn't, we ended up creating stored procedures and functions in SQL server that has it setup as a linked server. Which isn't great, but in our setup test and production sit on different dbo Schemas so I'm not sure EF would've been any easier.

Comment: Thanks for your info, so we will not use EF then